# Why might my jQuery only be working when I have an alert placed in front of the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is also written in alarming length, because I thought it might be a good teaching moment for other beginners as well.

The goal is to create som artsie-fartsie corner markers around an image, here is how it ought to look:
[image]

To achieve this, I first have a bounding/all encompasing `div`, then 2 empty `div`s, then the image. The bounding `div` is styled with some artsie-fartsie `box-shadowing` and padding, the 2 empty `div`s are to act as masks over the bounding `div` and under the image; i.e.:

[image]

It is noteworthy to mention that the image height is variable; where is where the difficulty originally stems from.

I originally attempted this 'masking' without the 2 empty `div`s, using CSS pseudo-elements `:before`& `:after`. Solving it this way is preferred, a little lighter and cleaner in my eyes, but using %'s on vertical margins is wonky. The 'vertical-cross mask' is easily acheivable. Here is some CSS, works without fault:

```css
.vert-review-image-cross-block {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: calc(100% + 12px);
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35%;
    top: -6px;
}
```

However, do the same for the 'horizontal' masking box does not work. Using % in a `margin-top` attribute does not work because for a reason that exceeds my intellect, CSS doesn't support this and calculates % against the width. Ergo the following CSS does not properly center the masking box on the 'y' axis:

```css
.horiz-review-image-cross-block {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70%;
    width: calc(100% + 12px);
    top: 0;
    left: -6px;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

The height is rendered properly, as 15% of the bounding box's height. But again, using % in margins only uses the width. My solution was then to use JS(jQuery) to manipulate the DOM - take away the `margin-top` in the CSS and add it with JS. This also supports the need for empty `div`s, as JS cannot affect pseudo elements. Below, in theory, ought to work fine. It's a tad on the verbose side, I have not attempted any refactoring because it's no behaving properly (called in a `document.ready()` function):

```js
function reviewImageHorizMaskMargin() {
    let reviewMediaImageBoxHeight = $(".review-media-image-box").height();
    $(".horiz-review-image-cross-block").css({"margin-top": (reviewMediaImageBoxHeight + 10) * 0.15 + "px"});
}
reviewImageHorizMaskMargin();
```

But it wasn't working, the applied margin was tiny. So I added a bunch of `console.logs` to see what's up:

```js
function reviewImageHorizMaskMargin() {
    console.log("$('.review-media-image-box').height()[1]: " + $(".review-media-image-box").height());
    let reviewMediaImageBoxHeight = $(".review-media-image-box").height();
    console.log("reviewMediaImageBoxHeight: " + reviewMediaImageBoxHeight);
    console.log("$('.review-media-image-box').height()[2]: " + $(".review-media-image-box").height());
    $(".horiz-review-image-cross-block").css({"margin-top": (reviewMediaImageBoxHeight + 10) * 0.15 + "px"});
    console.log("$('.review-media-image-box').height()[3]: " + $(".review-media-image-box").height());
}
reviewImageHorizMaskMargin();
```

The output was buggy as expected:

```
$('.review-media-image-box').height()[1]: 22
reviewMediaImageBoxHeight: 22
$('.review-media-image-box').height()[2]: 22
$('.review-media-image-box').height()[3]: 22
```

Then I added an `alert`, and something magical happend:

```js
...
console.log("$('.review-media-image-box')[1]: " + $(".review-media-image-box").height());
alert("$('.review-media-image-box')[1]: " + $(".review-media-image-box").height());
let reviewMediaImageBoxHeight = $(".review-media-image-box").height();
...
```

The alert was what I expected, the console output... not so much:

[image]

```
$('.review-media-image-box').height()[1]: 22
reviewMediaImageBoxHeight: 234
$('.review-media-image-box').height()[2]: 234
$('.review-media-image-box').height()[3]: 234
```

So how is it that the `alert` function 'sparks' the height to then be correct and thereby the margin to be rendered correctly?

Comment: `alert` is synchronous blocking code. So it blocks the execution flow while, in a different thread, the DOM continues getting rendered. So when you are using an alert you are pausing your code for the time that it takes you to click on "ok", the element gets rendered and it gets a height. If you don't block the thread, the block doesn't get rendered and its height is 0

Comment: Read and learn about the [document content loaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) and the [window load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). Then decide which one fits your needs and apply it to your problem.

Comment: Thanks to you both. Indeed running the function from within a `window.onload = () => {}` was the ticket.  Thanks